# Can't update $scope value in directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This directive fires when `ng-repeat` finishes using `scope.$last`:

```
simpleSearchApp.directive('afterResults', function($document) {
 return function(scope, element, attrs) {
   if (scope.$last){
    scope.windowHeight = $document[0].body.clientHeight;
   }
 };
});
```

I'm trying to update `$scope.windowHeight` with a new value but I can't access `$scope` inside the directive.

My `ng-repeat` HTML with directive:

```
 <div ng-show="items" class="ng-cloak" ng-repeat="item in items" after-results>
     {{item}}
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly saying I have also not understand why it's not updating. But the the alternate approach to update variable in controller is to define a function wich update the variable and call that function in controller from directive. Please take a look at the following example it might help you.

```js
angular.module('app',[]).controller('MyController',['$scope',function($scope){
  $scope.windowHeight = 0;
  
  $scope.updateWindowHeight = function(height){
    $scope.windowHeight = height;
  }
  
}])
.directive('afterResults', function($document) {
 return function(scope, element, attrs) {
   if (scope.$last){
      scope.windowHeight = $document[0].body.clientHeight;
      scope.updateWindowHeight( scope.windowHeight);//calling function in controller
   }
 };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.1" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyController">
  <div class="ng-cloak" ng-repeat="item in [1,2,3,4,5]" after-results="updateWindowHeight()">
    {{item}}
  </div>
  <hr/>{{ "$scope.windowHeight ="+windowHeight}}
</body>

</html>
```